# how to centre bootstrap column on carousel?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap page, which currently is just a carousel. I want to  centre my grid, which is on a bootstrap carousel, but unbroken and responsive. Is this possible ?

[demo link](http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/EKQBqq)

my html structure:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

    <div class="myDiv ">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">left column..</div>
              <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">right column..</div>
          </div>
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://www.aurumhotels.com.tr/resimler/normal/2015-08/FirmaArkaBanner1_4BuFjQUcCp3yALBpDUxLsignature.jpg" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://www.aurumhotels.com.tr/resimler/normal/2015-12/FirmaArkaBanner1_Isrgao2xv47jrJVBsf2Hfirmaarkabanner2.png" alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and my css structure

```
.myDiv{
      position: absolute;
      background:#fff;
      z-index:1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the .myDiv css class. Bootstrap already comes pre-built with a lot of css classes to help with your page layout such as container and contain-fluid. Instead of the following code:

```
<div class="myDiv ">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">left column..</div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">right column..</div>
      </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Just do something like:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">left column..</div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">right column..</div>
      </div>
</div>
```

And then just add styling to override the container-fluid columns to center the text.

Comment: Could you give more detail on what you mean by a centered grid and unbroken/responsive? Did you mean you want your two columns to be in the middle of the carousel screen, not at the top?

Comment: I meant my column has to be middle of the carousel screen horizantally

Answer (score 0):

you can add

```
.myDiv{
      position: absolute;
      background:#fff;
      z-index:1;
      left:50%;
}
```